# How to alter the SQL output messages

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I have multiple INSERT / SELECT statements as part of a single SQL data import script. When I run my script I get the output

```
(141926 row(s) affected)

(124366 row(s) affected)

(4 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

But what I would really want is

```
(141926 row(s) affected) - Customers Deleted

(124366 row(s) affected) - Customers Inserted

(4 row(s) affected) - Customers missing last name etc

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Is there anyway to do this in SQL??

Comment: You cannot really alter the output in a general way since SQL only queries, the results of the alterations are part of the database management layer. That said, some databases like pg/mssql do allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @yorick de Wid, in that I don' think you can customise the SQL output.

The closest that I can think of in SQL Server is to "roll your own", by doing something like:

```
declare @recordsaffected int
<execute your SQL statement here>
set @recordsaffected = @@ROWCOUNT
print convert(varchar,@recordsaffected) + ' <your message here>'
```